# Issue: ggplot2 replicates last plot of a list in grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I have some 16 plots. I want to plot all of these in  grid manner with ggplot2. But, whenever I plot, I get a grid with all the plots same, *i.e*, last plot saved in a list gets plotted at all the 16 places of grid. To replicate the same issue, here I am providing a simple example with two files. Although data are entirely different, but plots drawn are similar.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(scales)

set.seed(1006)
date1<- as.POSIXct(seq(from=1443709107,by=3600,to=1446214707),origin="1970-01-01")
power <- rnorm(length(date1),100,5)#with normal distribution
write.csv(data.frame(date1,power),"file1.csv",row.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
# Now another dataset with uniform distribution
write.csv(data.frame(date1,power=runif(length(date1))),"file2.csv",row.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
    path=getwd()
    files=list.files(path,pattern="*.csv")
    plist<-list()# for saving intermediate ggplots
    for(i in 1:length(files))
      {
      dframe<-read.csv(paste(path,"/",files[i],sep = ""),head=TRUE,sep=",")
      dframe$date1= as.POSIXct(dframe$date1)
      plist[[i]]<- ggplot(dframe)+aes(dframe$date1,dframe$power)+geom_line()
      }
    grid.arrange(plist[[1]],plist[[2]],ncol = 1,nrow=2)
```

Comment: Lose the call to `dframe` inside aes. It causes your issue, because if I understand correctly, aes doesn't get evaluated until a call to plot. At which point in time dframe contains the second set of data....

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Wasted nearly continuous 5 hours on this issue. Please put your comment an answer. This might save time for someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `dframe` from your call to aes. You should do that anyway because you have provided a data-argument. In this case it's even more important because while you save the ggplot-object, things don't get evaluated until the call to plot/grid.arrange. When you do that, it looks at the current value of `dframe`, which is the last dataset in your iteration.

You need to plot with:

```
ggplot(dframe)+aes(date1,power)+geom_line()
```

Comment: Furthermore, ggplot2::qplot() has the same problem. Only the last plot saved in a list gets plotted at all the places of a grid. How do you lose the call to dframe inside aes with qplot?

Comment: What fixed the problem for qplot() was wrapping in a function each qplot() call.